# How do I download an Android 10 system update over cellular after I already said I want it over wifi?

Tags: updates, android-10

My Moto G8 running Android 10 asked me how I want to get an update that just became available. I picked wifi only, but then realized I don't have wifi right now. I can't find any UI that would let me change my answer. It just says it's waiting for wifi and only offers me to check my wifi settings or configure "smart updates" which just means automatic download, install, and restart. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe this helps - from developer options (enable by tapping build number 7 or more times) find  “Download updates automatically.” or similar and disable it//next, go to  system updates in settings and search for updates. Maybe, you can now download over mobile data

Answer (score 0):

- Goto Settings
- Goto "About phone" or "Software Update" (depending on your phone)
- Find settings icon on top or setting item that says
- "Download Automatically" or "Automatically Download over wifi"
- **Toggle This once**
- It will prompt you if you wish to use cellular data. If it does not
  prompt. Then just restart and repeat this process once.